# Not searching in root for images in jquery tmpl mvc

Tags: jquery, jquery-templates

I have a jquery template and an image inside it like this:

```
<script id="myTmpl" type="text/html">
<div>
<img src="~/Images/myPic.png">
</div>
</script>
```

I got this error:

```
GET http://localhost:58864/Test/~/Images/myPic.png 404 (Not Found)
```

Why does it think my controller (named Test) is the root?

I have no problem placing the image outside the template.

Comment: `~` isn't MVC, this is webforms syntax. Just remove it you don't need it. starting with a `/` will look in the root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code:

```
<script id="myTmpl" type="text/html">
<div>
<img src="../Images/myPic.png">
</div>
</script>
```